# Mysql return none zero columns as zero

Tags: mysql, sql, null

i have a strange problem in the following query

```
SELECT id, productIDs FROM discount_codes WHERE productIDs=0 ORDER BY productIDs DESC
```

**RESULT**

```
id   |  productIDs

149  |  ,11,4
4    |  
7    |  
8    |
```

id 149 is not null or zero but return as result

[image]
can any one tell me how this could happen???

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why do you compare a varchar column like productIDs to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare a string with a number, it convers the string to a number first. Converting the string `,11,4` to a number produces `0` because it doesn't begin with a digit.

If you're looking for an empty string, use that, not the number `0`.

```
SELECT id, productIDs 
FROM discount_codes 
WHERE productIDs=''
```

If you also want to match an explicit `0`, match it as a string, not a number.

```
SELECT id, productIDs 
FROM discount_codes 
WHERE productIDs IN ('', '0')
```

Comment: thank you very much that's the point, you saved my time